# React 16 Ternary operator used with button, called with function gives error Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

My goal is when I click on any list items, I want to show hidden button as confirm. What I tried is to show button on-click on function name selectItem as follows :

```
          <Col xs={3}>
            <ul>
              <h2>Your orders </h2>
              {selectedItems.map((item, i) => (
                <li key={i}>
                  {item.name} {item.cost} {item.quantity}
                   <span onClick={() => this.deleteItem(i)}>cancel</span>
                </li>

              ))}
            </ul>
             {this.selectItem()
              ? <Button type="button" style={{ display: 'block' }}>Confrim</Button>
              : <Button type="button" style={{ display: 'none' }}>Confrim</Button>
            }

          </Col>
```

This gives the error as follows

```
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

The question is how I use the function call to display hidden button and hide when I remove all Items.Thanks.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Row,
  FormControl,
  Col,
  Button,
  Label,
  Modal,
  ButtonToolbar,
  Table
} from "react-bootstrap";

const MorningDrinks = [
  {
    id: "1",
    name: "Tea",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    name: "Coffee",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    name: "Milk",
    cost: 15
  }
];

const ChoclateDrinks = [
  {
    id: "4",
    name: "Smoothie",
    cost: 15
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    name: "Hot Chocolate",
    cost: 15
  }
];

class MenuCard extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedItems: []
  };

  selectItem = item => {
    const { counter, selectedItems } = this.state;
    const newItem = {
      ...item,
      quantity: 1
    };

    const el = selectedItems.filter(el => el.id === newItem.id);

    if (selectedItems.length === 0) {
      this.setState({
        selectedItems: selectedItems.concat([newItem])
      });
    } else {
      if (el.length) {
        const newSelectedItems = selectedItems.map(item => {
          if (item.id === newItem.id) {
            item.quantity++;
          }

          return item;
        });

        this.setState({
          selectedItems: newSelectedItems
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          selectedItems: selectedItems.concat([newItem])
        });
      }      
    }
  };

   deleteItem(i) {
    this.setState({
      selectedItems: this.state.selectedItems.filter((item, index) => {
        return index !== i;
      })
    });
  }


  render() {
    const { counter, selectedItems } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <p>
          Welcome {this.props.name}! Pick your any Break-fast menu you want
        </p>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={3}>
            <ul>
              <h2>Morning Drinks </h2>

              {MorningDrinks.map((item, i) => (
                <li
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  key={i}
                  onClick={() => this.selectItem(item)}
                >

                  {item.name} {item.cost}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
            <ul>
              <h2>Chocolate Drinks </h2>
              {ChoclateDrinks.map((item, i) => (
                <li
                  style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                  key={i}
                  onClick={() => this.selectItem(item)}
                >
                  {item.name} {item.cost}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          </Col>

          <Col xs={3}>
            <ul>
              <h2>Your orders </h2>
              {selectedItems.map((item, i) => (
                <li key={i}>
                  {item.name} {item.cost} {item.quantity}
                   <span onClick={() => this.deleteItem(i)}>cancel</span>
                </li>

              ))}
            </ul>
            <Button type="button" style={{display: 'none'}}>Confrim</Button>
          </Col>

          <Col xs={3}>
            <ul>
              <h3>Total</h3>

              {selectedItems.reduce(
                (acc, item) => acc + item.cost * item.quantity,
                0
              )}
            </ul>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MenuCard;
```

Comment: Using the array index as `key` is contrary to its purpose. Better use some unique property of `item`, like an id or don't use it at all

Comment: can you give an example of using a unique property of item ?

Comment: you mean like `key={item.id}` or `key={item.name}` as long as the `name` is unique

Comment: means what is your suggestion example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
this.selectItem()
```

Sets state, which can't be done inside a render method. Try to render the button by only reading from state.

```
{this.state.selectedItems.length > 0 ? ... : ...}
```

Comment: can you please provide any example of it?

Comment: Updated my answer!

Comment: it is working like charm. just to check array item length .. Great.